# Created instance of DefaultSavedRequest class for some reason contains not serializable 'request' field

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

Debugging issue with Redis serialization noticed, that during creation of the instance of following class:

*org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest*, resulting object (for some reason) contains **request** field of type *org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper*,

which actually represents the request, transfered to DefaultSavedRequest constructor as first parameter.
As the result, the stored session object fails serialization in Redis, and resuls in error.
The most interesting thing, is that this field not even present in DefaultSavedRequest itself.

Also wanted to mention, that I'm creating the object of anonymous class (that extends DefaultSavedRequest) with few extra fields. It looks like following:

```
final DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request, portResolver) {
                private final String referer = request.getHeader(REFERER)
                private final String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

                @Override
                public String getRedirectUrl() {
                    //getting custom redirect url
                }
            };
```

Attaching the screenshot from idea.
[image]

Using lib version: `spring-security-web-5.6.5`; java - `OpenJDK 17.0.5`

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? Facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 1):

this problem is related to the usage of anonymous class. The reference to request field is saved to the anonymous class because referer and contextPath attributes reference it. Not sure if this is a spring or a java thing.

Solved my problem by declaring a (named) class. Even a named inner class will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I commented back in 2022 that I also faced this issue. I arrived at the same solution as you've outlined here. This should be marked as the answer.